# significant difference in preference

Tags: r, contingency-tables

I have the following data

```
     X black brown
1 women    25    20
2   men    41    44
```

How can I see if there is a significant difference in preference between men and women using R

Answer (score 2):

Chi squared contingency test:

```
chisq.test(rbind(c(25,20),c(41,44)))
```

Look at `?chisq.test`. And I recommend that you read up on contingency tables if you don't understand what they do.